# Add tags to tag bar using xoxco tag plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I'm trying to add a tag from a list of words by just simply clicking the word and it gets added. I've tried to add a new value to the input in the HTML but that doesn't add a new tag in.

```
    $("li").click(function() {
        var word = $(this).text();

        var value = $('.tagBar').attr('value');
        var newValue = value+","+word;
        $('.tagBar').attr('value', newValue);
    });
```

I then tried to use the addTag(value,options) instead but I just kept getting errors.

How do you add a new tag without typing in the box and just clicking?

Answer (score 0):

I have a drop down list and a button to let the user add multiple items in a tag list using Xoxco tag input control. This is what I do:

```
$("#btnAgregarMaterial").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoids submitting the form

        var control = $("#cbbMateriales"); // gets drop down list
        var value = control.data("value"); // gets item value (ID)
        if (value > 0) { // if it is an item with ID greater than zero
            var text = control.text(); // get item text
            var tagsControl = $("#tags"); // gets tags input control
            tagsControl.addTag(text); // adds tag using addTag function
        }
    });
```

In order to add a tag, you need to use the function addTag. Setting the value directly won't work.